# uploading images with the help of arrays

Tags: php, mysql, image, file, upload

yesterday i started coding an upload file for uploading images to a directory. as i recognized that i have to use arrays to handle that a better way i got to the point that i'm using now:

```
 if(!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){  

                $allowed_extension = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'gif');

                foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key => $array_value){

                    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'][$key];
                    $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];

                    $file_extension = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
                    if (in_array($file_extension, $allowed_extension) === false){
                        $errors[] = 'file is not accepted';
                        }

                    if ($file_size > 2097152){
                        $errors[] = 'maxsize: 2MB';
                        }

                    $path = "a/b/c/"; 
                    $uploadfile = $path."/".basename($_FILES['image']['name'][$key]);

                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key], $uploadfile)){
                        echo "Das Bildmaterial wurde hochgeladen.";
                        }
                } 
        }
```

the problem is that i can upload the files all the time even when a non accepted ending is given. i dont understand why the upload happens when instead of uploading the errormessage should have been showed. i like to reach some more security with embedding allowed extensions to the code. if there is someone who could tell me what am i doing wrong, i would really appreciate. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two if-statements checking for exceptions but then do nothing with them.

Perhaps the following will help?

```
if(!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){  

    $allowed_extension = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'gif');

    foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key => $array_value){

        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];

        $errors = array ();
        $file_extension = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
        if (in_array($file_extension, $allowed_extension) === false){
            $errors[] = 'file is not accepted';
        }

        if ($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[] = 'maxsize: 2MB';
        }

        if (count ($errors) == 0) {
            $path = "a/b/c/"; 
            $uploadfile = $path."/".basename($_FILES['image']['name'][$key]);

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key], $uploadfile)){
                echo "Das Bildmaterial wurde hochgeladen.";
            }
        }
        else {
            // do stuff with errors
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use "continue"

eg

```
foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key => $array_value){

    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'][$key];
    $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];

    $file_extension = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
    if (in_array($file_extension, $allowed_extension) === false){
        $errors[] = 'file is not accepted';
        continue;
    }

    // the rest of your loop goes here
}
```

It will then go to the next image in the loop and not upload the image.

More information here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php